# Expected Value eiffel tower problem

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> At the Eiffel Tower at Paris, data shows that 62% of the visitors are foreigners. What is the expected value or average out of 7 would you expect to be foreigners? Calculate this two ways.

I don't know how to approach this problem. Shouldn't it be $7 • 0.62 = 4.34$? But my answer is wrong and I don't know how I can do this in "two ways".

Comment: why is it wrong?

Comment: There's a probability distribution chart for X=0,1,2,3,4,5,6 (I don't get why it is not to 7) and probability for each random variable. The answer is apparently the sum of all that divided by 7... apparently.

Comment: no, that ignores the fact that approximately 62% of the visitors are foreigneirs

Answer (score 0):

The number of visitors being foreigners is a binomially distributed random variable with $p=0.62$ and $n=7.$ Its expected value is
$$\mu=n p=7\cdot0.62=4.34.$$
Your answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly used linearity of expectation to find the expected number of foreign visitors.  We can confirm your result by applying the definition of the expected value of a discrete random variable $X$ that assumes the values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ with probabilities $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$, respectively.
$$E(X) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_kp_k$$

The number of foreign visitors can range from $0$ to $7$.  The probability that exactly $k$ of the visitors are foreigners is 
$$\binom{7}{k}(0.62)^k(1 - 0.62)^{7 - k} = \binom{7}{k}(0.62)^k(0.38)^{7 - k}$$
Hence, the expected number of foreign visitors in a group of seven people is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{7} k\binom{7}{k}(0.62)^k(0.38)^{7 - k} = 0\binom{7}{0}(0.62)^0(0.38)^7 + 1\binom{7}{1}(0.62)^1(0.38)^6 + 2\binom{7}{2}(0.62)^2(0.38)^5 + 3\binom{7}{3}(0.62)^3(0.38)^4 + 4\binom{7}{4}(0.62)^4(0.38)^3 + 5\binom{7}{5}(0.62)^5(0.38)^2 + 6\binom{7}{6}(0.62)^6(0.38)^1 + 7\binom{7}{7}(0.62)^7(0.38)^0 = 4.34$$